# TexStudio shows unrecognized command but renders perfectly anyway , why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, ubuntu

[image: Copied from tikz example page]

My actual question infact is , Can I remove these ? its a bit annoying and i probably wont be getting autocompletes for them .

Code taken from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/city/

Comment: What you like to remove? Please show us your code in form of small complete document, which we can test it as it is. From its image is not seen anything wrong. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: TeXstudio has a huge list of LaTeX commands (and possibly tries to parse your document preamble for command definitions) for auto-completion and to help users spot typos. But those lists are not always complete with all possible user-level (or semi-user-level) commands. In that case TeXstudio may highlight such commands in red and warn you that it doesn't know them. For your document it doesn't really matter what TeXstudio says, it is important what TeX says: If there are no errors or warnings, all commands were recognised. ...

Comment: ... If TeXstudio is missing some important user-level commands you can first try and see if it helps to manually enable the `.cwl` for the relevant package in case TeXstudio's auto-detect feature failed (you'll want to look at `tikz`, `pgf` or one of the related `.cwl` files; go to *Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion* and toggle the relevant packages on). But there is a real possibility that the commands are just missing in the `.cwl` files. Consider contributing them yourself or open an issue with the developers.

Comment: It seems that all commands that are highlighted as 'unknown' are either in [`pgfcore.cwl`](//github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/pgfcore.cwl) or [`tikz.cwl`](//github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/completion/tikz.cwl). That suggests that TeXstudio's auto-detection fails to detect those packages. Possibly because the packages are loaded hidden from TeXstudio's view via some other package or file. Possibly for a different reason. That is hard to say without having seen your preamble. Manually activating the `.cwl` files should make the commands recognised.

Comment: As at the compilation time one will note (yes or yes) what are really the undefined control sequences, aside of resolve this issue for this or that package, in `Options` > `Configure TeX Studio` > `Syntax Highlight`  you can set  a less intrusive background for `latexsyntaxMistake`

Comment: On the other hand,  if  in a particular document, some particular unknown command, said `\foo`,  is disturbing you, a quick a dirty  solution to disable only the highlight  of `\foo`   could be  `...\end{document} \def\foo{}`. In this case, the text after the document matter.

Comment: @moewe I tried that and now most of those "unrecognized Comand" are gone . I Should have included the code in the question fromt he beginning but i edited it now . Also Now only the `\draw` command shows unrecognized command other than that nothing is showing it . I only enabled tikz.cwl , there were like tikz-cd.cwl and another one .

Comment: These highlighting issues should be fixed in the last few versions of texstudio